# when is onAttach invoked?

Tags: android

[The android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) says that `The onAttach() callback is invoked when the fragment has been added to a FragmentManager and is attached to its host activity.`

A piece of my code in the activity:

```
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment  = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if(fragment == null){
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }

        Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_LOG_TAG, "onCreate(Bundle)");
    }
...
```

A piece of my code in the fragment:

```
...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.d(CRIME_FRAGMENT_LOG_TAG, "onAttach(Context)");
    }
...
```

The log:

```
...
2022-08-03 12:36:42.512 26035-26035/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/main_activity_log_tag: onCreate(Bundle)
2022-08-03 12:36:42.514 26035-26035/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/crime_fragment_log_tag: onAttach(Context)
...
```

As you can see `onAttach()` isn't invoked when the fragment is added to the `FragmentManager`.

**So when actually is `onAttach()` invoked?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment transactions are asynchronous by default. They are not executed immediately but just scheduled for execution at a later point.

If you want to make your fragment transaction synchronous, change `commit()` to `commitNow()`. Most of the cases you don't really need that.